# How to imitate std::string's find_first_not_of using strspn

Tags: c++, string, find

I'm trying to create a custom string class similar to std::string.

And I'm having a trouble implementing 'find_first_not_of'.

Here's my test code

```
#include <iostream>

class String {

private:

    char *m_data;
    int m_length;

    char *alloc(int size);
    int length() const {return m_length;}
    int size() const {return m_length;}
    const char *c_str() const {return m_data;}

public:

    String(const char *str=0);

    int find_first_not_of(const char *str);
    static const int npos;
};

const int String::npos = -1;

char * String::alloc(int size)
{
    char * str = new char[size+1];
    return str;
}

String::String(const char *str)
{
    if (!str) str = "";
    m_length = static_cast<int>(strlen(str));
    m_data = alloc(m_length);
    strcpy(m_data, str);
}

int String::find_first_not_of(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strspn(c_str(), str);

    if (len == 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return len;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    String A = "123";
    std::string B = "123";

    if (A.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == -1)
        std::cout << "A is digit" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "A is not digit" << std::endl;

    if (B.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == -1)
        std::cout << "B is digit" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "B is not digit" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result I see if I run the code.

```
A is not digit
B is digit
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Can someone please point me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, please don't add unrelated tags to your question (like for example the C tag for a C++ question). Secondly, what *is* the "value" of the string object, and what is `str`? Lastly, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry and thanks I just edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean when saying `A is not digit`? it's a string. Also, what should `String::find_first_if_not` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked just like std::string's `find_first_not_of`.

```
int String::find_first_not_of(const char *str, int pos)
{
    const int len = static_cast<int>(strspn(c_str() + pos, str));
    if (len + pos == m_length)
        return -1; //npos
    else
        return len + pos;
}
```

@Garmekain's explanation was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: should be `if (len + pos == m_length)`, otherwise you'll have a wrong result on strings that contain NUL characters.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing your `String::find_first_not_of` with `std::string::find_first_not_of`. They are different functions that have different functionality.

I really don't understand what `String::find_first_not_of` needs to do, but here is what each of them returns (one the length of the string and the other one the position):

std::string::find_first_if_not (from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/)):

> The position of the first character that does not match.
>   If no such characters are found, the function returns string::npos.

strspn (from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/)):

> The length of the initial portion of str1 containing only characters that appear in str2.
>   Therefore, if all of the characters in str1 are in str2, the function returns the length of the entire str1 string, and if the first character in str1 is not in str2, the function returns zero.

So even the inner working of the functions are different.

You should be able to follow based on this info.